# deep linking in react native using custom scheme link

Tags: python, android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

Hi I have done deeplinking in react native, Initially for testing purpose i have create on html page with hyper link if i click on that link if app is installed app is opening.
I have been stuck on one thing where i am trying to put the same link in email template but that link is not clickable. Using Interakt for mailing service and backend is python

**HTML page for internal testing**

```
<a href="customer://renewal">Plan renewal</a>
```

**in email template block of link:**

```
 <div class="column">
            <span class="align_center_btn">
                <a href="customer://renewal" style=" background: #285295;
                border-radius: 6px;
                padding: 10px 16px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                border: none;">Renew again</a>
                <p style="line-height: 20px;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-family: 'Open Sans';
                font-style: normal;">We will remember you on  <br />{{plan_end_date}} </p>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the full stack (including the web application), you can consider trying this approach: Instead of linking directly from the email into the app, have your email body link to a regular webpage that you create. That webpage can then manage the redirection of the user into the app (such as a regular Javascript-based redirect, or other approaches).

Many email client apps are funny about following links that are not prefixed with `https://` - you might be facing an issue like this (blocking non-https links to prevent phishing scams). Therefore, try to first redirect from the email body onto your own https based webpage specifically made to capture this traffic, and then that page redirects them to your `customer://renewal` URL scheme.